# String indices must be integers - Django

Tags: python, django, dictionary

I have a pretty big dictionary which looks like this:

```
{
'startIndex': 1,
'username': 'myemail@gmail.com',
'items': [{
    'id': '67022006',
    'name': 'Adopt-a-Hydrant',
    'kind': 'analytics#accountSummary',
    'webProperties': [{
        'id': 'UA-67522226-1',
        'name': 'Adopt-a-Hydrant',
        'websiteUrl': 'https://www.udemy.com/,
        'internalWebPropertyId': '104343473',
        'profiles': [{
            'id': '108333146',
            'name': 'Adopt a Hydrant (Udemy)',
            'type': 'WEB',
            'kind': 'analytics#profileSummary'
        }, {
            'id': '132099908',
            'name': 'Unfiltered view',
            'type': 'WEB',
            'kind': 'analytics#profileSummary'
        }],
        'level': 'STANDARD',
        'kind': 'analytics#webPropertySummary'
    }]
}, {
    'id': '44222959',
    'name': 'A223n',
    'kind': 'analytics#accountSummary', 

And so on....
```

When I copy this dictionary on my Jupyter notebook and I run the exact same function I run on my django code it runs as expected, everything is literarily the same, in my django code I'm even printing the dictionary out then I copy it to the notebook and run it and I get what I'm expecting.

Just for more info this is the function:

```
google_profile = gp.google_profile # Get google_profile from DB
print(google_profile)
all_properties = []
for properties in google_profile['items']:
    all_properties.append(properties)

site_selection=[]
for single_property in all_properties:
    single_propery_name=single_property['name']
    for single_view in single_property['webProperties'][0]['profiles']:
        single_view_id = single_view['id']
        single_view_name = (single_view['name'])
        selections = single_propery_name + ' (View: '+single_view_name+' ID: '+single_view_id+')'
        site_selection.append(selections)
print (site_selection)
```

So my guess is that my notebook has some sort of json parser installed or something like that? Is that possible? Why in django I can't access dictionaries the same way I can on my ipython notebooks?

**EDITS**

More info: 
The error is at the line: `for properties in google_profile['items']:`
Django debug is: `TypeError at /gconnect/ string indices must be integers`

Local Vars are:

```
all_properties =[]
current_user = 'myemail@gmail.com'
google_profile  = `the above dictionary`
```

Comment: Where in the function is the error occurring?  Can you show the actual error message?

Comment: Hey @ScottHunter I've added more info, thanks

Comment: google_profile is a string, so you cannot use ['items'], this works only on dicts, defaultdicts and OrderedDicts or classes implementing __getitem__

Comment: That was correct, and json solved the problem with:
`import json`
`s = "{'muffin' : 'lolz', 'foo' : 'kitty'}"`
`json_acceptable_string = s.replace("'", "\"")`
`d = json.loads(json_acceptable_string)`
`# d = {u'muffin': u'lolz', u'foo': u'kitty'}` from [Other Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/988228/convert-a-string-representation-of-a-dictionary-to-a-dictionary)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So just to make it clear for who finds this question:

If you save a dictionary in a database django will save it as a string, so you won't be able to access it after.

To solve this you can re-convert it to a dictionary:

The answer from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/988228/convert-a-string-representation-of-a-dictionary-to-a-dictionary) worked perfectly for me, in other words:

```
import json
s = "{'muffin' : 'lolz', 'foo' : 'kitty'}"
json_acceptable_string = s.replace("'", "\"")
d = json.loads(json_acceptable_string)
# d = {u'muffin': u'lolz', u'foo': u'kitty'}
```

There are many ways to convert a string to a dictionary, this is only one. If you stumbled in this problem you can quickly check if it's a string instead of a dictionary with:

```
print(type(var))
```

In my case I had:

`<class 'str'>`

before converting it with the above method and then I got

`<class 'dict'>`

and everything worked as supposed to